# Paste array to certain rows and column within table

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, listobject

I wrote a function to write the contents of a 2-dimensional array to an existing table. Nothing will be removed from the table. The new rows must be added at the bottom. The number of columns depends on the size of the 2nd dimension of the array and I take as an assumption that the table has enough columns.

My issue is: how can I refer to the range in the table without:
a) having the sheet with the table as the active sheet and
b) without having to reference the worksheet (like is now present in the code; see below)?

See the code below that I tried.

```
Function PasteArrayToTable(tblDestinationTable As ListObject, arrSourceArray() As Variant)

'Note: works for arrays starting with index = 1 (option base 1)!

Dim lngNewRows As Long
Dim lngHeaderRowPosition As Long
Dim intHeaderColumnPosition As Long
Dim lngFirstRow As Long
Dim lngLastRow As Long
Dim intFirstColumn As Integer
Dim intLastColumn As Integer
Dim lngNrOfRecordsAtStart As Long

'Number of rows to be added
lngNewRows = UBound(arrSourceArray, 1)

'If the array contains rows, then write them to the destination table
If lngNewRows > 1 Then

    'Get header position of destination table
    lngHeaderRowPosition = tblDestinationTable.HeaderRowRange.Row
    intHeaderColumnPosition = tblDestinationTable.HeaderRowRange.Column

    'Get number of records in table before pasting array, in order to remove afterwards an empty row if the table has 0 rows
    lngNrOfRecordsAtStart = tblDestinationTable.ListRows.Count

    'Add rows to table
    tblDestinationTable.Resize tblDestinationTable.Range.Resize(tblDestinationTable.Range.Rows.Count + lngNewRows)

    'Determine positions where to write array to
    lngFirstRow = lngHeaderRowPosition + tblDestinationTable.ListRows.Count + 1 - lngNewRows
    lngLastRow = lngHeaderRowPosition + tblDestinationTable.ListRows.Count
    intFirstColumn = intHeaderColumnPosition
    intLastColumn = intFirstColumn - 1 + UBound(arrSourceArray, 2)

    'Write array to determined positions. Note: there's no check whether the table has the required number of columns, nor
    'whether the number of lines fit on the page
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wks = Worksheets("Blad1")
    With wks
        .Range(.Cells(lngFirstRow, intFirstColumn), .Cells(lngLastRow, intLastColumn)).Value = arrSourceArray
    End With

    'Remove empty row if present
    If lngNrOfRecordsAtStart = 0 Then
        tblDestinationTable.ListRows(1).Delete
    End If

End If

End Function
```

So how to make a reference to the 'cells' in the table?

Comment: `ListObject.Parent` returns a reference to the sheet the table is on.

Comment: You might also consider working with the `DataBodyRange` of the table as opposed to the `Range`.

Comment: @BigBen: Thank you very much, I solved it!

Comment: @BigBen: Yes, something with 'tblDestinationTable.DataBodyRange' would be nicer, however how to refer then to the combination of a subset of columns with a subset of rows?

Comment: You could use `DataBodyRange.Cells` with references to the specific row(s) and column(s) in question.

Comment: @BigBen: Ah yes, I figured it out with DataBodyRange.Cells and now have to adjust some code to start at the correct row. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below the code that solves the issue.

```
Function PasteArrayToTable(tblDestinationTable As ListObject, arrSourceArray() As Variant)

'Note: works for arrays starting with index = 1 (option base 1)!

Dim lngHeaderRowPosition As Long
Dim intHeaderColumnPosition As Long
Dim lngFirstRow As Long
Dim lngLastRow As Long
Dim intFirstColumn As Integer
Dim intLastColumn As Integer

'If the array contains rows, then write them to the destination table
If UBound(arrSourceArray, 1) > 1 Then

    'Get header position of destination table
    lngHeaderRowPosition = tblDestinationTable.HeaderRowRange.Row
    intHeaderColumnPosition = tblDestinationTable.HeaderRowRange.Column

    'Determine positions where to write array to
    lngFirstRow = lngHeaderRowPosition + tblDestinationTable.ListRows.Count + 1
    lngLastRow = lngFirstRow + UBound(arrSourceArray, 1) - 1
    intFirstColumn = intHeaderColumnPosition
    intLastColumn = intFirstColumn + UBound(arrSourceArray, 2) - 1

    'Write array contents to the bottom of the destination table
    With tblDestinationTable.Parent
        .Range(.Cells(lngFirstRow, intFirstColumn), .Cells(lngLastRow, intLastColumn)).Value = arrSourceArray
    End With

End If

End Function
```

Comment: Or `With tblDestinationTable.Parent`